# Showing Grid view instead of Map

Tags: android

I'm very new to android. I'm developing an app which shows the current location using Google Map.

I've generated key for this application. But It doesn't show the map instead, it shows Grid View.

---

```
The following is the code..!
//MActivity


package velu.ndot.hosp;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HospitalActivity extends MapActivity {

 private LocationManager myLocationManager;
 private LocationListener myLocationListener;
 private TextView myLongitude, myLatitude;

 private MapView myMapView;
 private SeekBar myZoomBar;

 private MapController myMapController;

 private void CenterLocation(GeoPoint centerGeoPoint)
 {
  myMapController.animateTo(centerGeoPoint);


  myLongitude.setText("Longitude: "+
   String.valueOf((float)centerGeoPoint.getLongitudeE6()/1000000)
   );
  myLatitude.setText("Latitude: "+
   String.valueOf((float)centerGeoPoint.getLatitudeE6()/1000000)
   );
 };

 private void SetZoomLevel()
 {
  int myZoomLevel = myZoomBar.getProgress()+1;
  myMapController.setZoom(myZoomLevel);
  Toast.makeText(this,
    "Zoom Level : " + String.valueOf(myZoomLevel),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 };

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.newtab);
  myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
  myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitude);
  myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitude);
  myZoomBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.zoombar);

  myMapView.setSatellite(true); //Set satellite view
  myMapController = myMapView.getController();
  SetZoomLevel();

  myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

  myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

  myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    0,
    0,
    myLocationListener);

  //Get the current location in start-up
  //check LastKnownLocation, if not valid, skip it.
  Location initLocation=
   myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  if(initLocation != null)
  {
   GeoPoint initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(
     (int)(initLocation.getLatitude()*1000000),
     (int)(initLocation.getLongitude()*1000000));
   CenterLocation(initGeoPoint);
  }
  myZoomBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(myZoomBarOnSeekBarChangeListener);
 }

 private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener myZoomBarOnSeekBarChangeListener =
  new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
     boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SetZoomLevel();
   }

   public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

 };

 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

  public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   GeoPoint myGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(
    (int)(argLocation.getLatitude()*1000000),
    (int)(argLocation.getLongitude()*1000000));

   CenterLocation(myGeoPoint);
  }

  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
    int status, Bundle extras) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 };


//Manifest file
```

---

This is my manifest.xml File and I have got permission with the internet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="velu.ndot.hosp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HospitalActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps">  </uses-library>
    </application>
</manifest>

//Layout
```

My layout design..!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  > 
 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/longitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Longitude:"
  />
  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/latitude"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Latitude:"
  />
   <SeekBar
   android:id="@+id/zoombar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="20"
    android:progress="0"/>
 </LinearLayout>
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/mapview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:clickable="false"
  android:apiKey="key**********************"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looking all right in your code. Please try to take another map key and then check may be this will solve your problem .
As your code is similar to:
http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/how-use-google-maps-android-application